# Splunk ignores and truncates thousand separator commas in automatically identified numeric field

Tags: splunk

We have splunk spit out log statements like 
latency=1,840 . Splunk identifies latency = 1
latency=524 . Splunk identifies latency = 524

Splunk identitfies latency as Numeric but takes value only as 1 and truncates the other decimal values for case 1. And so the timechart over its average also gets affected. I was hoping to use "convert rmcomma" but that didn't help as the latency field has already been stripped of numbers and commas before supplying to convert rmcomma.

Answer (score 1):

Also at: http://answers.splunk.com/answers/232083

Question: "We have splunk spit out log statements" - what does this mean? Where is the information coming from?

I think Splunk is seeing the comma as identifying a "multi-valued field". A Splunk administrator could change how this is parsed, but not without answering my earlier question.

Do this within your search to fix the problem:

```
 yoursearchhere
 | eval latency=if(mvcount(latency)>1,mvjoin(latency, ""),latency)
 | whateverelse
```